# Проблема с некорректной работой bs4 BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, bs4

```
response = requests.get(main_page)
html = response.content
html
```

Выдает, соответственно, неформатированный html файл. И, казалось бы, BeautifulSoup должен сделать из этого структурированное дерево

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
soup
```

Однако результат все еще остается неструктурированным (html.parser, кстати, не был видел для программы, что странно, пришлось скачивать отдельно, но результаты оказались теми же). После этого я попробовал использовать этот кусок, чтобы проверить работает ли библиотека вообще:

```
soup.html.head.title
```

И все-таки текст она выдает заголовка, однако, тэги  расположены прямо у краев строки, чего быть не должно:

```
<title>42 870 объявлений - Купить 1-комнатную или 2-комнатную квартиру в Москве, недорого - база объявлений ЦИАН</title>
```

При последующих попытках с soup.find программа вообще перестала что либо выдавать.
Друзья, я не смог найти хоть немного похожую проблему, может кто-нибудь знает ответ на эту мистику?

В комментариях мне подсказали, что надо бы указать ссылку на сайт, поэтому вот фрагмент:

В обучающих целях использовал сайт циана:

```
main_page = 'https://www.cian.ru/cat.php?deal_type=sale&engine_version=2&offer_type=flat&region=1&room1=1&room2=1' 
response = requests.get(main_page)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
soup
```

И html.content и soup выдают неструктурированные данные При попытке выгрузки оттуда по find ничего не происходит:

```
obj = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':"serp-item__price-col"})
```

Юпитер плюется и говорит, что переменная obj является NoneType

Comment: вместо 'lxml' не пробовали стандартный 'html.parser' из коробки? так: soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser') тоже остается неструктерированным? а, сори, дочитал вопрос... пробовали... а какой адрес сайта?

Comment: Для решения проблемы нужна ссылка на страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно пронял суть вашей проблемы, то не получается избавится от тегов `<title>`

Как вариант решения данной проблемы то можно сделать так:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


main_page = 'https://www.cian.ru/cat.php?deal_type=sale&engine_version=2&offer_type=flat&region=1&room1=1&room2=1'
response = requests.get(main_page)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title.get_text())
```

Ответ выглядит следующим образом

```
42 309 объявлений - Купить 1-комнатную или 2-комнатную квартиру в Москве, недорого - база объявлений ЦИАН
```

Пример работы данного метода можно найти в документации [тут](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=get_text()#get-text).

Comment: К сожалению, проблема заключается не в этом. Проблема именно со структурой, т.е. при запуске самого soup результат не структурирован как html разметка, а идет сплошным текстом. Я подозреваю, что проблема с переменной obj, о которой я говорил ранее, с этим и связана.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась проще, чем ожидалось. В общем, как я понял, проблема была не в библиотеке, а в самом питоне. Скорее всего терялись пакеты библиотеки из-за неправильной установки самого питона. При полном сносе языка и переустановке, соответственно переустановки самой библиотеки bs4 все заработало.